# Asp.net MVC Routing Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have 2 views in my App

1:Views->Season->ViewSeason

[alt text http://img102.imageshack.us/img102/9207/viewsseasonsx4.jpg](http://img102.imageshack.us/img102/9207/viewsseasonsx4.jpg)

2:Views->Admin->Season->ViewSeason

[alt text http://img242.imageshack.us/img242/1911/viewsadminsr4.jpg](http://img242.imageshack.us/img242/1911/viewsadminsr4.jpg)

How i write Controller for this? pls help me.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest thing to do would be to collapse Admin/Season into AdminSeason and have an AdminSeasonController.cs.

Then update your routing table so the /Admin/Season routes to AdminSeasonController.

This is untested, but it could look like this in your Global.ascx (above the out-of-box MVC route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "AdminSeason",
            "Admin/Season",
            new { controller = "AdminSeason", action = "Index" }
           );
```

Here are some other questions re: MVC Routing:

- [ASP.Net MVC route mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926/asp-net-mvc-route-mapping)
- [ASP.NET MVC routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118851/asp-net-mvc-routing)
- [ASP.NET MVC Routing Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377117/asp-net-mvc-routing-question)
- [Problem with ASP.NET MVC routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492625/problem-with-asp-net-mvc-routing)